# Why is refreshing a database view required in our app?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a report generator that consists of nested views to prevent redundant code.  We discovered that in some situations we are required to "refresh" the higher level views (using `sp_refreshview`) after editing a lower level one.  If we don't, the fields will actually return data from the wrong fields in the nested view.

Why is this?  Our team lead suggested that perhaps it's because we have a few areas in the older views where `select *` was used (to be fair there are about 200 of them). Could this cause it, or is there something else we may be doing wrong?

Our database is MSSQL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by refresh?

Comment: sorry about that.  we run the transact-sql command sp_refreshview to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views are created with schema definitions that are not updated without refreshing the view itself.  So updating underlying tables/views that cause any schema changes will require a refresh of the main view in order to update the view schema.  This can still be true even when the logic in the main view remains correct, because the schema behind it is wrong and needs to be refreshed.

You can create your views with `SCHEMABINDING`, which will prevent changes to underlying objects while the view exists, and thus kind of 'force remind' you to update your view (as your will have to modify it first or drop it then recreate it after you make those underlying changes).  Alternatively you can continue to refresh the view after changes are made.  Both arrive at the same end result.

For me, the decision on which approach to use would fall on how impactful it would be if someone makes an underlying change and the view does not get refreshed.

Comment: so basically no matter what approach we pick, the result isn't automatic?

Comment: @JohnLord That's correct. You'll need to include sp_refreshview as part of your deploy so that it always gets executed after changes, or schedule it to run before your reports so you know that view's definition is always up to date when the reports are run.